# angular.js library "angular-img-http-src" with Edge browser

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge

I'm using angular.js library "angular-img-http-src" and my current browser is Edge.
I ran into an issue with uploading images.
In the Chrome browser, there is no problem, the image uploads through an internal file server so the URL points to the file's path and the user token is added to the request header.
In Edge browser, the URL converts to an unrecognized path.
Anyone experienced something similar and can advise a solution?

Comment: any error in console??

Comment: First I had a 401 unauthorized Error response for my HTTP GET request of the image, so I tried to add the user's login token as a query parameter to the URL and then I received a response "[object Object]"

Comment: Can you please inform us which exact version of MS Edge browser you are using for making this test? Which OS build you are using? Let us know if there is any sample code or steps which we can refer for producing the issue. Only description will not give proper idea about the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Sure, sorry. The Edge version is "Microsoft Edge 44.18362.329.0". I'm using Windows 10 Home , 64-bit, OS build- 18362.356.

Comment: Please provide the sample code with detailed steps to test the issue on our side.